# Steel Threaded Pipe/Compression Fitting Replacement

Tags: plumbing

[image]

Hello all,

I've run into an issue when replacing my faucet in my bathroom. It had some really old piping coming off the wall, and as you can see, the compression fittings that were on the steel threaded pipe are shot. I just stopped off at the "best" plumbing store in town and they said they had no solutions. I would (and eventually will) replace the entire T assembly off the wall, but money is tight and I'm looking for a solution to get my faucet working for now with the steel threaded pipes. I live in a condominium complex and my HOA wants to charge me up the wazoo to have the water shut off to the entire building for a few hours.

Any help/ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are you located? Where I'm from (Canada) I've only seen corrugated  hose used on domestic water systems to connect the hot water tank (ie larger diameter then a faucet supply).

Comment: I live in the Los Angeles, California area.

Comment: Must be a western US thing. A friend in Arizona recently posted a picture of a similar corrugated tube which fed his toilet.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you will need to replace the entire hose. I've never seen one quite like the one in your picture and I can't tell what the connection type is at the other end, but this site might help you determine what you have/need: [Stainless Steel Corrugated Hose for Faucet](http://www.cx-hoses-fittings.com/corrugated-hose/stainless-steel-corrugated-hose-pipe-tube-for.html).

As far as shutting off the water to the entire building; there’s typically a shutoff valve at the wall, or at minimum a separate water shutoff for just your condo unit. There should be no need to shut off the entire building.

Comment: The shut off is in the picture, it's the white knob. The line to the faucet is before the shutoff, so there's no way for me to replace the hose and T valve without shutting the water off to my unit... which can only be done by killing everyone else's water. Great design right? Not......

Comment: If the shown valve is turned off and there is no water coming out of the hose, as shown in the picture, you should be able to unscrew the hose form the valve and install a replacement one, similar to the ones in the link above. There should be no need to relace the valve itself.

Comment: @pdd  it appears that the hose is built into the valve and is not able to be unscrewed from the valve.  This means the valve would need to be replaced  thus the need to shut off water to the whole condo.  The homeowner should check with an attorney about his legal rights to have the water shut off for maintenance  without undue strain on his wazoo.

Comment: @Alaskaman As I've never seen the valve in question before, you may be right. However I would be very surprised if the hose could not be unscrewed and replaced as that would defeat the propose of the valve. Regardless, each residential unit should have it's own shut off valve that isolates the unit's water system from the building's distribution system. If the unit is not isolatable, there is most likely a code issue and the resident should not have to pay for the isolation of the building itself.